# SQL Query hardCoded Update

Tags: sql

If I execute this query I get the result below

```
SELECT Month_Name,
Count(SalesID) AS Toal
FROM Sales
Group by Month_Name
```

I have the following Result

```
Month_Name  Toal
Apr-15      341
May-15      314
Jun-15      342
Jul-15      327
Aug-15      179
Sep-15      234
Oct-15      286
Nov-15      171
```

PROBLEM: In previous month I have data for Feb-15 and Mar-15 but they are not on the table. I have been told not to update the table with the figures
I was given for Feb-15 and Mar-15. The figures are as follows

```
Feb-15 = 349

Mar-15 = 312
```

Is there a way I can write a query to reflect both months by hardcoding it in the query so that the result will look like the table below

```
Month_Name  Toal
Feb-15      349
Mar-15      312
Apr-15      341
May-15      314
Jun-15      342
Jul-15      327
Aug-15      179
Sep-15      234
Oct-15      286
Nov-15      171
```

Comment: I assume you use MySQL since the query you use does not throw an error?

Comment: I suppose that the table also has a sort column by which you order your results?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(
SELECT
 Month_Name,
 Count(SalesID) AS Toal
FROM
 Sales
Group by 
 Month_Name
) 
UNION ALL 
(
SELECT 
  'Feb-15' AS Month_Name, 
  349 AS Total
) 
UNION ALL 
(
SELECT 
  'Mar-15' AS Month_Name, 
  312 AS Total
)
```

Comment: Correct answer, but you should use UNION ALL, as there are no duplicates to eliminate. The parentheses are superfluous.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Agreed on the `UNION ALL`, and edited accordingly. Parenthesis are for readability more than anything else.

Answer (score 1):

You'd add the two records with UNION ALL. In order to produce such records, you simply select them without a table or from DUAL - which of the two depends on the DBMS you are using.

As you certainly want the records to be sorted by month, there must be a sort key in your table to make this possible. In the following query I assume it to be a positive numeric value named sortkey and the two months to come first. Adjust this according to your needs.

```
select month_name, total
from
(
  select month_name, count(*) as total, sortkey from sales group by month_name
  union all
  select 'Feb-15', 349, -2 -- here you may have to add FROM DUAL
  union all
  select 'Mar-15', 312, -1 -- here too
) all_months
order by sortkey;
```